# Regular Expression to capture the first <p> of HTML

Tags: .net, regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
(?:<(?<tag>\w*)>(?<text>.*)</\k<tag>>)
```

I want it t grab the text within the first HTML element.

eg.

```
<p>This should capture</p>This shouldn't
```

Works, but ...

```
<p>This should capture</p><p>This shouldn't</p>
```

Doesn't work. As you'd expect, it returns:

```
This should capture</p><p>This shouldn't
```

I'm racking my brains here. How can I just have it select the FIRST inner text?

(I'm trying to be tag-agnostic, so `<strong>This should match</strong>` is equally appropriate, etc.)

Comment: **DO NOT PARSE HTML USING Regular Expressions!**

Comment: And there was me thinking I should do that instead of building a state machine. Any reason why?

Comment: See this answer to a similar question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Fair enough. I know what you're saying, I just wanted the first bit of text so I didn't anticipate parsing an extensive document. Thanks.

Comment: @Program: And what do you expect to do in the case of `<p> text <p> more text </p> </p>`?  You can't keep track of arbitrary nesting like this using RegEx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

For example:

```
doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("p").First().InnerText
```

Comment: I actually am looking at using the HtmlAgilityPack for another section of the project so this is "on the radar". I might just use it in the longer term.

Answer (score 2):

Stop. Just stop. If you are parsing HTML, use an HTML parser (or XML if you're dealing with valid XHTML). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a non-greedy * selection, you should add an ? after the *.

```
(?:<(?<tag>\w*)>(?<text>.*?)</\k<tag>>)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to go for that only because it is very simple work I am doing and I am coping with failure elegantly. Then again @BlueRaja has just blown a hole in my theory. Sorry.